# What's the point of GitHubGist vs. Public Repos

Tags: github

I still don't get the purpose of a Git Gist even after reading this: https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/

If I've got a public repo, what's the difference?  I'm sharing files that way too

Comment: I would say Gists are smaller versions of full-blown Github repos that are lacking key features of repos such as: branching, submitting pull requests, and creating issues. You would use Gists to hold a small amount of code (that may in itself be a full application) that you want to share with someone for a specific reason. Overall, I see Gists as being more casual than repos.

Comment: hmm, weird.  I think it's useless but maybe I don't see the light yet.  I see it just convoluting regular github because now you have these things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My primary use of gist is for private code sharing, if I raise a support call with MS etc I can send in config files etc, without having to paste them into the support log, and without them being publicly accessible.

They're also useful because they're not complete repositories in your normal github account. I'll put  things there that I wouldn't put in a full repository. So larger code snippets that I've found useful etc.

I never use them for this! but if you're a blogger etc, they are good for using for embedded code etc.

And they can also be created anonymously. Which again I've never done but I can see the benefit of (because they're publically searchable)

mostly they are just useful because they're a smaller unit of code that doesn't clog up your primary account. If you know they're there, and what they can do, at some point you'll probably use them!